# Swig / Python memory leak detected

Tags: python, memory-leaks, swig

I have a very complicated class for which I'm attempting to make Python wrappers in SWIG. When I create an instance of the item in Python, however, I'm unable to initialize certain data members without receiving the message:

```
>>> myVar = myModule.myDataType()
swig/python detected a memory leak of type 'MyDataType *', no destructor found.
```

Does anyone know what I need to do to address this? Is there a flag I could be using to generate destructors?

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13587791/swig-and-c-memory-leak-with-vector-of-pointers/13593596#13593596

Answer (score 12):

SWIG always generates destructor wrappers (unless `%nodefaultdtor` directive is used). However, in case where it doesn't know anything about a type, it will generate an opaque pointer wrapper, which will cause leaks (and the above message).

Please check that `myDataType` is a type that is known by SWIG. Re-run SWIG with debug messages turned on and check for any messages similar to

```
Nothing is known about Foo base type - Bar. Ignored
```

Receiving a message as above means that SWIG doesn't know your type hierarchy to the full extent and thus operates on limited information - which could cause it to not generate a dtor.

Comment: Which SWIG debug flag should be turn on? Some of them produce awful lot of information. Under which flag should I be looking for messages you mentioned?

Answer (score -13):

The error message is pretty clear to me, you need to define a destructor for this type.

Comment: This isn't correct. It's entirely possible to have defined a destructor, or be using a default default destructor and not see this error. The important thing is that SWIG knows about the existence of such a destructor. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13587791/swig-and-c-memory-leak-with-vector-of-pointers/13593596#13593596