# Detected a memory leak... no destructor found - for enums

Tags: python, swig

This is about embedded python using swig.

I have an `std::map<enum, std::string>` exposed to python (embedded python). When the script is executed, swig spits out the below "warning" at the end (when the map goes out of scope - I guess):

> swig/python detected a memory leak of type 'std::map< MyEnum, std::string>
>   ... no destructor found

The .i file is:

```
enum MyEnum {
 ...
};

typedef std::map<MyEnum, std::string>  MyTypedef;
%template(MyTypedef) std::map<MyEnum, std::string>;
```

Things are ok if I replace `MyEnum` with int all over the code. Don't know why swig needs any special destruction when enums are not PyObjects! Am I missing something? Is there some `%magic_operator` which will help.
Note: I do not want to suppress the "memory leak" warning all together.

Took a hard look at the wrapper generated by swig but in vain.

Comment: Does SWIG know the full definition of the enum? Check the answers to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/918180/swig-python-memory-leak-detected

Answer (score 0):

Could be a problem with declaration order: the std::map %template must be declared AFTER MyEnum is added to the SWIG interface.

I have failed to do this in the past (though in my case the map key was a typedef alias to an unsigned int), and saw the exact same set of symptoms reported here.

Comment: The std::map %template ARE mentioned AFTER MyEnum as shown above. So, looks like there is something more to this. Note that this happens only for Enums in maps. An int-to-string map is all good.