# How to fix "swig/python detected a memory leak of type 'HWND *', no destructor found"?

Tags: python, c++, windows, memory-leaks, swig

Consider this mcve:

**mcve.h**

```
#pragma once

#include <windows.h>

class Windows {
  public:
    static HWND GetActiveWindow();
    static HWND GetForegroundWindow();
};
```

**mcve.cpp**

```
#include "mcve.h"

HWND Windows::GetActiveWindow() {
    return ::GetActiveWindow();
}
HWND Windows::GetForegroundWindow() {
    return ::GetForegroundWindow();
}
```

**mcve.i**

```
%module mcve

%include <std_string.i>
%include <std_vector.i>
%include <typemaps.i>
%include <windows.i>
%include <cpointer.i>
%include <carrays.i>

%{
#include "mcve.h"
%}


%include "mcve.h"
```

**setup.py**

```
from distutils.core import Extension
from distutils.core import setup

setup(
    name="mcve",
    ext_modules=[
        Extension(
            "_mcve",
            sources=["mcve.i", "mcve.cpp", "mcve_wrap.cpp"],
            swig_opts=["-c++", "-python"],
            include_dirs=["."],
            library_dirs=[
              "D:/software/vcpkg/installed/x86-windows/lib"
            ],
            libraries=["user32"]
        )
    ],
    py_modules=["mcve"],
)
```

In order to run it, make sure you adjust properly the `library_dirs` variable and then just type:

```
python setup.py build_ext --inplace
```

If the extension has been generated succesfully then you just run `python test.py` and you should see an output similar to this:

```
>python test.py
swig/python detected a memory leak of type 'HWND *', no destructor found.
swig/python detected a memory leak of type 'HWND *', no destructor found.
```

I know you can use swig `-nodefaultdtor` to not generate implicit default destructors, I've tried and that didn't make any difference.

For the sake of completeness, here's roughly how the HWND typedefs would look like:

```
typedef PVOID HANDLE;
typedef HANDLE HWND;
typedef void *PVOID;
```

**QUESTION:** What's the proper way in swig to prevent that memory leak of HWND?

Comment: Related question: [https://stackoverflow.com/a/920988/3809375](https://stackoverflow.com/a/920988/3809375)

Comment: FYI `test.py` is mentioned, but not provided.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SWIG wasn't provided a definition of `HWND` and treats it as an opaque class.  Note that `%include "mcve.h"` does NOT recurse into `#include <windows.h>` and only processes code directly in `mcve.h`, so SWIG has no definition at all.

There are a couple of solutions:

- Give SWIG a definition that it understands.  SWIG has a default for `void*`, and would correctly handle the following definition:

```cpp
%module mcve

%{
#include "mcve.h"
%}

typedef void* HWND;

%include "mcve.h"
```

- You can make custom typemaps instructing Python how to convert an HWND to and from a Python object.  Unlike the previous solution, which returns a SWIG-wrapped void* object, this solution treats handles as integers:

```
%module mcve

%{
#include "mcve.h"
%}

%typemap(in) HWND %{
    $1 = PyLong_AsVoidPtr($input);
%}

%typemap(out) HWND %{
    $result = PyLong_FromVoidPtr($1);
%}

%include "mcve.h"
```